# How can i refer my modified Corda Core project's jar file into Tutorial project

Tags: gradle, corda

I have git clone the corda core project and Tutorial project based on master M13. I just changed some content in a kt file of Corda core project. And run gradlew build to publish in the jar into local.  I want to use this modify jar into my Tutorial project. Seem it's not ok for now. could you have some suggestion and doc help to me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `gradlew install` from Corda to publish your modified version of Corda to your local Maven repository.

The bigger issue is that the CorDapp tutorial will default to pulling down the milestones from online repositories, instead of your local maven. Go to the build.gradle, java-source/build.gradle and kotlin-source/build.gradle files, and delete any references to jcenter() or mavenCentral().